# Strategies for dealing with split application

Tags: wcf, iis

To deal with recent growth our application has been split across two sets of separate infrastructure. Approximately half of our customers are on set 1 and the other half are on set 2.

Both sets have different urls (api1.ourdomain.com and api2.ourdomain.com).

Problem is clients accidentally putt the wrong url and then wonder why they get error messages.

Other then user education any other strategies for dealing with this mess?

Is it possible to redirect requests to the correct endpoint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your question is detailed enough to provide meaningful feedback.  There are obviously several factors that could easily contribute to a recommendation.

Does your application make use of user profiles (or a similar construct)?  If so you might consider associating a primary URI for each user in their profile and include logic in your application to interrogate the profile for each request and redirect if a user goes to the wrong URI.

Is this an authorization issue?  If so you might consider including some basic authorization routing that provides a custom 403 page with the proper URL.

If you could provide additional detail I think we could be more helpful.